# SQL Server OPENROWSET without SYSADMIN role

Tags: sql-server, openrowset

We extensively use the `OPENROWSET` function to import `.CSV` and Excel files into our SQL Server 2012 environment, using MSDASQL or ACE:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET ('MSDASQL',
                 'DRIVER={MICROSOFT access TEXT DRIVER (*.TXT, *.CSV)};', 
                 'SELECT * FROM E:\INCOMING\REPORT_EXTRACT.CSV')
```

Or using ACE:

```
SELECT * FROM     OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','TEXT;DATABASE=E:\INCOMING\;HDR=YES;', 'SELECT     * FROM [REPORT_EXTRACT.CSV]');
```

We're experiencing the classic error message:

> Msg 7415, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' has been denied. You must access this provider through a linked server.

The ONLY workaround to enable this, is granting said user(s) with the `SYSADMIN` role - obviously not ideal.

The location of the file(s) is on the server itself, for which the users accessing DO have the necessary permissions to access that file folder. The SQL Server service is running under the local system account with permission to interact with the desktop.

- [image: List item]

We've tried the following workarounds/fixes to no avail:

**1** Executed the following code:

```
EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N’Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0′ , N’AllowInProcess’ , 1
GO

EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N’Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0′ , N’DynamicParameters’ , 1
GO
```

**2* The DisAllowAdHocAccess registry fix:

This is the current state:

[image]

**3** Adding the ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permission to the said users

We have dozens of expressions and files within our procedures that use OPENROWSET, therefore BULK INSERT, building SSIS packages, leverage Excel files as linked servers are NOT feasible options.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Running MSSQL under local System account is dangerous, and hardly less bad than granting SA, especially if users have access to the base OS.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the tip ! What are the risks of running as Local System? 
And What should it be run under?

Comment: Local System: depending on what you have enabled, a user could break out of MSSQL to act as the system. Then the whole server is compromised. They could read password hashes of domain admins for example. Normally when you setup MSSQL, it creates a service account. Basically just a regular account, with a random unchanging password. I'm unsure how safe it is to do after you've set it up.

Comment: A solution for your problem is probably to make a sproc to do the import with `EXECUTE AS sa` permissions

Comment: ..@DepthofField..the providers in the question are slightly mixed up. MSDASQL is a bridge provider between OLE & ODBC. OPENROWSET requires and ole provider, but{MICROSOFT access TEXT} is an ODBC one, so in order to bridge the gap, MSDASQL is used. `OPENROWSET (MSDASQL[OLEDB-->ODBC], [ODBC]DRIVER={MICROSOFT access})` The error Ad hoc access to OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' has been denied indicates the problem : there is no adhoc access for MSDASQL. Instructions at : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/configure-permissions-access-remote-data#add-the-disallowadhocaccess-value

Comment: ..alternatively, since ACE.OLEDB is already configured...you could ingest the csv using that ole provider: `SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Text;Database=E:\INCOMING;HDR=NO', 'SELECT * FROM [REPORT_EXTRACT.CSV]')`

Comment: Hi @lptr - believe me, I've tried both ACE and MSDASQL. Identical outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - After YEARS of troubleshooting, I finally figured out what it was!

The registry entry value that controls the Allowing of Ad-hoc access, relies on the `DisallowAdHocAccess` being in that EXACT sentence case.

In our case, the "A" in AdHoc was not capitalized:

[image]

To fix this, I:

1. Deleted the registry value as described
2. Re-enabled the `Disallow AdHoc Access` option (Which re-created the registry value)

[image]

3. Manually set the Registry `DisallowAdHocAccess` value to "0"

[image]

Problem solved!